# Is it better to use Many To Many Polymorphic Relations than having 2 intermediate tables?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Currently I have 3 tables - `images`, `tags` and `tag_image`. This allows me to have an image that has many tags associated to it. Now I am trying to add the same functionality to my videos, however, I'm not sure which way is the more efficient one.

My first option is just creating a second intermediate table `tag_video` and doing the same thin I have done with my images.

The second option I found out about yesterday is this - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Using Many To Many Polymorphic Relations allows me to only have 1 intermediate table which seems good to me, however, since I'm not that knowledgeable I decided to ask here which is better.

One of the end goals I have is to be able to have a view which displays BOTH images and videos that share a certain tag and I'm not sure how would I do that if I have 2 intermediate tables.

Comment: go with laravel documentation `ManyToMany` polymorphic relationship. in fact doc matched perfectly for your design. Easily you can insert  and fetch data

Comment: As a side note, your first intermediate table should be named `image_tag` following Eloquent's standard.

Comment: Exactly what you asked for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rhby8SBEYh8